# Is Unity going to use the GNOME 3 stack?

Tags: unity, gnome

Will the next release of Ubuntu make use of the new gnome stuff or will it sill be based on gnome 2 like in 11.04?

Answer (score 3):

Unity is totally GNOME 3/GTK3 ready. We just need to port bamf to use gdbus instead of dbus-glib and we are ready to roll!

Answer (score 2):

The full details behind what will make it in 11.10 will be decided shortly.  However, consider gnome3 backend stuff as close to 100% !  Whether it is gnome 3 or gnome 3.2 is another matter.  Keep reading the blogs...